# Why does this HOC causes RTK Query to go in a infinite request loop?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, redux-toolkit

I have a Loading Higher Order Component that I use it to wrap a Nav component :

```js
//Nav.tsx
import { FC } from "react";
import { withLoading } from "../../components/Loading";
import { useAuthenticateQuery } from "@/store";

const Nav:FC = () => {
    const { data } = useAuthenticateQuery();


  return (
    <h1>
      {data?.data.displayName} {data?.data.email}
    </h1>
  );
}

export default withLoading(Nav);
```

```js
//Loading.tsx
import React, { FC } from "react";

interface props {
  isLoading: boolean;
}

export function withLoading<T extends props = props>(WrappedComponent: FC<T>) {
  const ComponentWithLoading = (props: T) =>
    props.isLoading ? <div>Loading...</div> : <WrappedComponent {...props} />;

  return ComponentWithLoading;
}
```

I used it in my homepage passing the isLoading property to it like this :

```
//index.tsx
'use client'
import Nav from "./login/Nav";
import { useAuthenticateQuery } from "@/store";
import BigButton from "@/components/BigButton";



export default function Home() {
  const { data, error, isLoading, refetch } = useAuthenticateQuery();
  

  return (
  <Nav isLoading={isLoading} />
 )
}
```

However I was testing to see what happened if the server was the down and the request returned an error and I'm getting an infinite loop, with RTK Query refetching data all the time. If I remove the withLoading and just return Nav the data is fetched only once.

Any ideas on how to address this issue?